# Live Screencast under Linux

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, latency, screencasts

I was having some difficulty with running a Live Screencast under Linux.  I've found jtvlc and tried using that, but whenever I use it the stream comes out either blank or lagged with extremely high latency. I have a fast internet connection and a fast computer, but am I perhaps taxing it too much?

Any ideas on what I could possibly be doing wrong?

```
# 1. Get an account on http://www.justin.tv/
# 2. Copy streaming key from: http://www.justin.tv/broadcast/adv_other
# 2. Install VLC: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/
# 3. Get Win/Mac/Lin Stream Client: \
# http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/Linux_Broadcasting_API
# 4. Adjust the vlc parameters to your liking and run VLC like this

#!/bin/bash
cvlc screen:// --input-slave=pulse:// \
    --screen-width 1920 \
    --screen-height 1080 \
    --screen-fps 5 \
    -v input_stream \
    --sout='#duplicate{ dst="transcode{ scale=1, venc=x264{ keyint=60 }, vcodec=h264, vb=600, acodec=mp4a, ab=32, channels=2, samplerate=22050 } :rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=1234,sdp=file:///tmp/vlc.sdp} "}' \
    --sout-transcode-threads=4 & sleep 2

# 5. Run JTVLC to stream like this:
./jtvlc/jtvlc omnipotententity censored /tmp/vlc.sdp

# Notes:
#- If you want to see what you're about to stream add 'dst=display, '
# before 'dst="transcode['
# More about the VLC parameters: http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/screen
```

Update:

I've fixed my issue... for the most part.  I was trying to put too much information through my upstream.  I've since reduced my resolution and used the crf option for x264.

Now my script lookes like this:

```
# 1. Get an account on http://www.justin.tv/
# 2. Copy streaming key from: http://www.justin.tv/broadcast/adv_other
# 2. Install VLC: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/
# 3. Get Win/Mac/Lin Stream Client: \
# http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/Linux_Broadcasting_API
# 4. Adjust the vlc parameters to your liking and run VLC like this

#!/bin/bash
cvlc screen:// --input-slave=pulse:// \
    --screen-width 1920 \
    --screen-height 1080 \
    --screen-fps 5 \
    -v input_stream \
    --sout='#duplicate{ dst="transcode{ scale=1, width=1280, height=720, venc=x264{ keyint=60, crf=35 }, vcodec=h264, acodec=mp4a, ab=32, channels=2, samplerate=22050 } :rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=1234,sdp=file:///tmp/vlc.sdp} "}' \
    --sout-transcode-threads=4 & sleep 2

# 5. Run JTVLC to stream like this:
./jtvlc/jtvlc omnipotententity redacted /tmp/vlc.sdp

# Notes:
#- If you want to see what you're about to stream add 'dst=display, '
# before 'dst="transcode['
# More about the VLC parameters: http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/screen
```

That being said, I still do have a few problems.  Sometimes when I change the stuff on the screen a bunch it fails to encode properly.  Which is odd, because screencasting through Skype 4.0 works just fine.  So there's still a few kinks to work out.

I'm leaving the bounty open and I'm actively trying things mentioned.  I'll still assign the bounty, even though I self-resolved.

Comment: When you try to run it, what are the utilizations for CPU, GPU, bandwidth (in % terms)

Comment: CPU is totally fine (less than 50% on any one core), I'm unsure how to measure GPU usage, bandwidth usage hovers right around whatever I put vb= to. (For obvious reasons.)  If I set the vb number lower it works much better, but I also get video tearing, artifacting and encoding messes.  It might be lost packets, but it also might be that the vb rate is too low?  Is there a nice way to set VLC to variable bitrate?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: What's your internet connections maximum bandwidth/throughput?

Comment: If you get this working, let me know. It'd make it so I don't have to startx, open a browser, and start up my webcam.

Comment: @Oliver: 30mbps down / 5mbps up

Comment: The answer to your second part is right there: "used the crf option for x264." / "when I change the stuff on the screen a bunch it fails to encode properly."  Constant Rate Factor means effectively constant quality.  If you do a lot at once, that means you updated it a lot, which means more bandwidth under CRF mode.  Constant bit rate is what you probably want to go for.

Comment: But it's really not the answer to my question, because even when using a constant bit rate far lower than my bandwidth can take I get the symptoms originally described.  Using CRF doesn't reach my upload limit even when I do lots of stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a shot in the dark but I have a feeling that

> --screen-fps **5** \

should be the problem. try to change 5 to a higher value like 50 and see what happens.

Comment: 5 means a rather choppy frame rate, but 50 is way too much.  At most I'd do around 30 (that's roughly what movies usually are), but with his bandwidth restriction, I'd probably not go above 10.

Comment: Actually bumping up to 24 gets rid of the artifacting issues that I was having before.

Comment: May I know your graphic card model?

Comment: NVidia 260 GTX If I recall correctly.

Comment: Ok can you change your screen size to 1280 x 720, set fps to 24 and try it? after changing your desktop size [from your desktop property settings] don't forget to change --screen-width 1920 \  --screen-height 1080 \ to 1280 and 720. I'm guessing the random failures to encode properly is because it needs to resize your captured video runtime and that might cause this issue.

Comment: It actually seems to work fine even at full resolution, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Good to know mate, have fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another product that you can try :

[WebcamStudio For GNU/Linux](http://www.ws4gl.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..!

```
# 1. Get an account on http://www.justin.tv/
# 2. Copy streaming key from: http://www.justin.tv/broadcast/adv_other
# 2. Install VLC: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/
# 3. Get Win/Mac/Lin Stream Client: \
#    http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/Linux_Broadcasting_API
# 4. Adjust the vlc parameters to your liking and run VLC like this

#!/bin/bash
cvlc screen:// \
    --screen-width 1576 \
    --screen-height 886 \
    --screen-fps 5 \
    --screen-caching 200 \
    --screen-top 75 \
    -v input_stream \
    --sout='#duplicate{ dst="transcode{ scale=1, width=630, height=354, venc=x264{ keyint=60 }, codec=h264, vb=600, acodec=mp4a, ab=32, channels=2, samplerate=22050 } :rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=1234,sdp=file:///tmp/vlc.sdp} "}' \
    --sout-transcode-threads=2 &

# 5. Run JTVLC to stream like this:
jtvlc justintvusername streamkey /tmp/vlc.sdp

# Notes:
#- If you want to see what you're about to stream add 'dst=display, '
# before 'dst="transcode['
# More about the VLC parameters: http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/screen
```

If that doesn't works you can try [Live Desktop Streaming via DLNA on GNU/Linux](http://realmike.org/blog/2011/02/09/live-desktop-streaming-via-dlna-on-gnulinux/).

Comment: Man, that script looks weirdly familiar.